# How to get \textcite{} to insert a non-breaking space between the first name initial and the last name in the main text?

Tags: biblatex

Suppose I use biblatex and that I cite two papers by two authors with the same last name, A. Smith (2019) and B. Smith (2020). If I use, say `\textcite{Smith2020}`, it may compile as

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur **B.**
>
> **Smith (2020)** adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod

How can I get it to compile as the following?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>
> ****B.** Smith (2020)** adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is probably

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{name:giveni-family}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \mkbibcompletenamegivenfamily{%
    \ifdefvoid{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\addnbspace}%
    \ifdefvoid{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
       \ifprefchar
         {}
         {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
    \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
    \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:giveni-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:giveni-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{aelk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
@book{celk,
  author    = {Catherine Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Other Dionsaurs},
  year      = {2021},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sit amet igitur a \textcite{aelk}
ipsum \autocite{celk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sit amet igitur a A. Elk (1972) ipsum (C. Elk 2021)]

do note that using a nonbreakable space in this position does not necessarily guarantee that the whole name moves to the next line. You could also get an overful line.